# How do I convert all strings in a list of lists to integers?

Tags: python, string, integer

I have a tuple of tuples containing strings:

```
T1 = (('13', '17', '18', '21', '32'),
      ('07', '11', '13', '14', '28'),
      ('01', '05', '06', '08', '15', '16'))
```

I want to convert all the string elements into integers and put them back into a list of lists:

```
T2 = [[13, 17, 18, 21, 32],
      [7, 11, 13, 14, 28],
      [1, 5, 6, 8, 15, 16]]
```

Answer (score 654, accepted):

[`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) is the Python standard built-in function to convert a string into an integer value. You call it with a string containing a number as the argument, and it returns the number converted to an integer:

```
>>> int("1") + 1
2
```

If you know the structure of your list, T1 (that it simply contains lists, only one level), you could do this in Python 3:

```
T2 = [list(map(int, x)) for x in T1]
```

In Python 2:

```
T2 = [map(int, x) for x in T1]
```

Comment: why not `T2 = map(lambda lol: map(int, lol), T1)`? Either map or list comprehensions, both is silly ;)

Comment: @flyingsheep Double map seems silly to me, this seems just fine.

Comment: How about removing Python 2 example (because of end of life for Python2) ?

Comment: @flyingsheep `map(lambda)` is also silly ;) A list comprehension is more natural and easier to read.

Comment: @Alisso I moved it lower. Legacy Python 2 code is still in use, and anyway, don't worry about removing stuff from an answer unless it makes it significantly worse.

Answer (score 29):

You can do this with a list comprehension:

```
T2 = [[int(column) for column in row] for row in T1]
```

The inner list comprehension (`[int(column) for column in row]`) builds a `list` of `int`s from a sequence of `int`-able objects, like decimal strings, in `row`. The outer list comprehension (`[... for row in T1])`) builds a list of the results of the inner list comprehension applied to each item in `T1`.

The code snippet will fail if any of the rows contain objects that can't be converted by `int`. You'll need a smarter function if you want to process rows containing non-decimal strings.

If you know the structure of the rows, you can replace the inner list comprehension with a call to a function of the row. Eg.

```
T2 = [parse_a_row_of_T1(row) for row in T1]
```

Answer (score 21):

Using only list comprehensions:

```
[[int(y) for y in x] for x in T1]
```

Answer (score 10):

Instead of putting `int( )`, put `float( )` which will let you use decimals along with integers.

Comment: Can you explain more details on you answer?

Answer (score 9):

I would agree with everyone’s answers so far but the problem is that if you do not have all integers, they will crash.

If you wanted to exclude non-integers then

```
T1 = (('13', '17', '18', '21', '32'),
      ('07', '11', '13', '14', '28'),
      ('01', '05', '06', '08', '15', '16'))
new_list = list(list(int(a) for a in b) for b in T1 if a.isdigit())
```

This yields only actual digits.  The reason I don't use direct list comprehensions is because list comprehension leaks their internal variables.

Comment: `isdigit` is tricky, try it on `-1`. `int(<str>)` is the way to check by `try`/`except`.

Answer (score 8):

```
T3=[]

for i in range(0,len(T1)):
    T3.append([])
    for j in range(0,len(T1[i])):
        b=int(T1[i][j])
        T3[i].append(b)

print T3
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Rather than only post a block of code, please explain why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not 

an answer.

Answer (score 8):

Try this.

```
x = "1"
```

x is a string because it has quotes around it, but it has a number in it.

```
x = int(x)
```

Since x has the number 1 in it, I can turn it in to a integer.

To see if a string is a number, you can do this.

```
def is_number(var):
    try:
        if var == int(var):
            return True
    except Exception:
        return False

x = "1"

y = "test"

x_test = is_number(x)

print(x_test)
```

It should print to IDLE True because x is a number.

```
y_test = is_number(y)

print(y_test)
```

It should print to IDLE False because y in not a number.

Comment: Your is_number function is wrong. '1' is not equal to 1. This is not Perl. :-P

Comment: Don’t reinvent the wheel, use `x.isnumeric()`.

Answer (score 4):

Using list comprehensions:

```
t2 = [map(int, list(l)) for l in t1]
```

Comment: in python 3 this returns a list of map objects :(

Answer (score 2):

Yet another functional solution for Python 2:

```
from functools import partial

map(partial(map, int), T1)
```

Python 3 will be a little bit messy though:

```
list(map(list, map(partial(map, int), T1)))
```

we can fix this with a wrapper

```
def oldmap(f, iterable):
    return list(map(f, iterable))

oldmap(partial(oldmap, int), T1)
```

Answer (score 2):

See this function

```
def parse_int(s):
    try:
        res = int(eval(str(s)))
        if type(res) == int:
            return res
    except:
        return
```

Then

```
val = parse_int('10')  # Return 10
val = parse_int('0')  # Return 0
val = parse_int('10.5')  # Return 10
val = parse_int('0.0')  # Return 0
val = parse_int('Ten')  # Return None
```

You can also check

```
if val == None:  # True if input value can not be converted
    pass  # Note: Don't use 'if not val:'
```

Comment: `eval` is evil: you should replace it with `ast.literal_eval`.

Answer (score 1):

If it's only a tuple of tuples, something like `rows=[map(int, row) for row in rows]` will do the trick. (There's a list comprehension and a call to map(f, lst), which is equal to [f(a) for a in lst], in there.)

Eval is *not* what you want to do, in case there's something like `__import__("os").unlink("importantsystemfile")` in your database for some reason.
Always validate your input (if with nothing else, the exception int() will raise if you have bad input).

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.5.1 things like these work:

```
c = input('Enter number:')
print (int(float(c)))
print (round(float(c)))
```

and

```
Enter number:  4.7
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has built in function int(string) and optional parameter base.

if your string contains an Integer value, it will convert that to the corresponding Integer value.
However if you have decimnal number as string you'll need float() to convert it.

Usage:

```
a = '22'
b = int(a)
```

and

```
if a = '22.22'
b = int(a) '''will give error, invalid literal for int().'''
b = float(a) '''will convert the string.'''
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like this:

```
T1 = (('13', '17', '18', '21', '32'),  
     ('07', '11', '13', '14', '28'),  
     ('01', '05', '06', '08', '15', '16'))  
new_list = list(list(int(a) for a in b if a.isdigit()) for b in T1)  
print(new_list)
```