# <enumerate object at 0x7f0211ea2360>

Tags: python, enumerate

I ran the following code in Python3.5.2 and got the corresponding output

```
>>> example = ['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> enumerate(example)
<enumerate object at 0x7f0211ea2360>
```

I'm unable to understand what is the meaning of this output.Why didn't the output come like this

```
 (0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (4, 'e')
```

When i used a list to contain these tuples the output was satisfactory

```
>>> list(enumerate(example))
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (4, 'e')]
```

Note : I'm a newbie in python and when i posted this question i didn't know about map function so i didn't refer this question 
[Why does map return a map object instead of a list in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015439)

Comment: because `enumerate` is an iterable. The values are generated on demand.

Comment: If you followed a tutorial based on Python 2, that may be the reason for your confusion: This behaviour has been introduced with Python 3. In that case, you should probably switch to a different tutorial.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does map return a map object instead of a list in Python 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015439/why-does-map-return-a-map-object-instead-of-a-list-in-python-3) (It's the same principle and answers discuss more generally than `map`)

Comment: @JonasSchäfer not for `enumerate`, no. It has always been a generator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's purely a choice of design in Python 3 because [**`enumerate`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) is often used in loops/list comprehension, so no need to generate a full-fledged list and allocate memory for a temporary object which is very likely to be unused afterwards.

Most people use `for i,e in enumerate(example):` so they don't even notice the generator aspect, and the memory/CPU footprint is lower.

To get an actual `list` or `set`, you have to explicitly force the iteration like you did.

(note that as opposed to `range`, `zip` or `map`, `enumerate` has always been a generator, even in python 2.7, good choice from the start)

Answer (score 1):

Understanding enumerate

Say `train_ids` is a list of my training object.

```
aa=enumerate(train_ids)
type(aa)
for i in aa:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
l1 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
for i in enumerate(l1):
   print i
```

Comment: @BhargavRao doing some polishing ? :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I did not get you.

Comment: doesn't matter it was a joke about polishing bad posts.