# Why does map(), filter() and zip() returns custom objects in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, filter, mapping

What is the point in python 3 that they changed `map()` to return a map object, `filter()` to return a filter object and `zip()` to return a zip object, instead of python 2's list.

Every time I use these functions, I still use it as `list(map())` to change it back to a list. While python 2 is already a list. Is there anything special for the new objects?

```
zipped = zip([1,2,3],[3,2,1])
# what are you supposed to use a <zip object at 0x104316ec8> for??
zipped = list(zip([1,2,3],[3,2,1]))
# this is way more useful [(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1)]
```

As I checked to see if the new objects has new new methods, but no... D: that's all they have:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__',
 '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', 
'__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', 
'__next__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', 
'__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

Can someone list all the reasons why they did this and the uses for the new objects that doesnt require list() around them? And is it faster than python 2's map(), filter() and zip()?

Comment: Because they are lazy iterators that don't keep intermediate results in memory, but produce items as you need them.

Comment: If you just need to iterate over the result (overwhelmingly the most common use case for `zip`, and common for `map` and `filter`), you don't need a list.

Comment: If you are using `list(map(<whatever>))` etc then you aren't taking advantage of the lazy, memory efficient nature of the new constructs.

Comment: Pay particular attention to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40015658/5014455) answer in the dupe.