# concurrent requests with queue and thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, request

I am trying to make concurrent API calls with python.
I based my code on the solution (first answer) presented in this thread: [What is the fastest way to send 100,000 HTTP requests in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632520/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-send-100-000-http-requests-in-python)

Currently, my code is broken.
I have a main function which creates the queue, populates it, initiates the threads, starts them, and joins the queue.
I also have a target function which should make the get requests to the API.

The difficulties I am experiencing right now is that 
the target function does not execute the necessary work.
**The target is called, but it acts as the queue is empty.**
The first print is executed ("inside scraper worker"), while the second ("inside scraper worker - queue NOT empty") is not.

```html
def main_scraper(flights):
  print("main scraper was called, got: ")
  print(flights)
  data = []
  q = Queue()
  map(q.put, flights)
  for i in range(0,  5):
      t = Thread(target = scraper_worker, args = (q, data))
      t.daemon = True
      t.start()
  q.join()
  return data
```

```html
def scraper_worker(q, data):
  print("inside scraper worker")
  while not q.empty():
    print("inside scraper worker, queue not empty")
    f = q.get()
    url = kiwi_url(f)
    response = requests.get(url)
    response_data = response.json()
    results = parseResults(response_data)
    q.task_done()
    print("task done. results:")
    print(results)
    #f._price = results[0]["price"]
    #f._url = results[0]["deep_link"]
    data.append(results)
  return data
```

I hope this is enough information for you to help me out. 
Otherwise, I will rewrite the code in order to create a code that can be run by anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that the flights are not being put on the queue. `map(q.put, flights)` is lazy, and is never accessed so it is as if it didn't happen. I would just iterate.

```html
def main_scraper(flights):
  print("main scraper was called, got: ")
  print(flights)
  data = []
  q = Queue()
  for flight in flights:
      q.put(flight)
  for i in range(0,  5):
      t = Thread(target = scraper_worker, args = (q, data))
      t.daemon = True
      t.start()
  q.join()
  return data
```

Comment: yeah, that was the problem. I created a new post related to the map function, after i discovered that problem. What do you mean by the map is lazy? related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49039676/py-queue-library-mapping-array-to-queue-py3-issues

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015439/why-does-map-return-a-map-object-instead-of-a-list-in-python-3 This post has some good thoughts on how maps are lazy. What I mean is they don't execute right away but they do later when they are accessed.