# Py Queue library - mapping array to queue - py3 issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, queue

I previously posted a question regarding a script which performed 
conccurent requests. This script was failing, because of an empty queue.

I further investigated the problem and came with this simple problem.
We have a function which creates a queue based on an array.
We then iterate over the queue, printing the value, until the queue is empty.

```html
try:
  from queue import Queue
except:
  pass
try: 
  from Queue import Queue
except:
  pass

def test():
  q = Queue()
  a = [1,2,3]
  map(q.put, a)
  print("queue size after insertion: ", str(q.qsize()))
  while not q.empty():
    item = q.get()   
    print(item)
     

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print("Starting test.")
  test()
  print("Test finished.")
```

In python2, everything works fine. The queue size after insertion is 3

In python3, after insertion, the queue size is 0, and thus the iteration over the queue is not being executed.

SOLUTION:
changing the insertion method fixed the problem.
replace:

```
map(q.put, a)
```

for:

```
 for item in a:
     q.put(item)
```

I wonder what causes this problem with the map function in python3.