# Python: Retrieve the length of a list value that's within a list value

Tags: python

I recently picked up Python and I am alternating between this [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) and a book called [Automate The Boring Stuff With Python](https://automatetheboringstuff.com).

I find the book quite easy to understand and the exercises are fun.
There is one in particular that I just solved but honestly, I am not satisfied with my answer.

In the question, one is given a grid as follows:

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
        ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

Using loops only, one is then required to produce the following output:

```
..00.00..
.0000000.
.0000000.
..00000..
...000...
....0....
```

My solution (which works) to this problem is as follows:

```
for y in range(0,len(grid[0])):
    for x in range(0, len(grid)):
        print(grid[x][y], end='')

    print()
```

My problem is the **grid[0]**. I have tried to generalize the code to accommodate scenarios in which the lists within **grid** are of different values, but failed.

My question, therefore, is how can I retrieve the `len` of **grid[0]** in general variable terms?

In other words, how can I retrieve the length of a list within a list?

Comment: So, do you want a nice solution with `zip` or are we stuck to only `for` and `print` here? :)

Comment: Kind of confusing what exactly you are asking, but just do `len(grid(row_number))`

Comment: @Tomothy32 that's exactly what I did. But how would I loop through list values of varying length? Let's imagine that I do not know their lengths either.

Comment: @timgeb Thanks. The book is yet to introduce zip so just for/while and print.

Comment: Do you want something like `for sublist in grid: len(sublist)`?

Comment: That sounds like it. Could you please share a working example, and then I will apply to my particular problem? @Tomothy32

Answer (score 2):

For example taking the longes of all the content list:

```
>>> grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
...         ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
...         ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
...         ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
...         ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
...         ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
...         ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
...         ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
...         ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
>>> 
>>> max(map(len, grid))
6
```

BTW, a pythonic way of solving that (without loops) would look like this `list(zip(*grid))`:

```
>>> for l in zip(*grid):
...     print("".join(l))
... 
..00.00..
.0000000.
.0000000.
..00000..
...000...
....0....
```

Comment: You don't need to convert your `zip` object into `list` since you iterating over it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need to retrieve length.

You can do it in one line without knowing dimensions:

```
print('\n'.join(map(lambda x: ''.join(x), zip(*grid))))
```

Step by step:

1. `zip(*grid)` will transpose your 2-d array

```
>>> list(zip(*grid))
[('.', '.', '0', '0', '.', '0', '0', '.', '.'),
 ('.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'),
 ('.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'),
 ('.', '.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'),
 ('.', '.', '.', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'),
 ('.', '.', '.', '.', '0', '.', '.', '.', '.')]
```

2. `map(lambda x: ''.join(x), zip(*grid))` will join every line

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: ''.join(x), zip(*grid)))
['..00.00..', '.0000000.', '.0000000.', '..00000..', '...000...', '....0....']
```

3. And finally `'\n'.join` joins with separator as new line

```
>>> print('\n'.join(map(lambda x: ''.join(x), zip(*grid))))
..00.00..
.0000000.
.0000000.
..00000..
...000...
....0....
```

**Note**: we could also omit 3rd step by `print`ing with `sep='\n`, however in Python3:
[Why does map return a map object instead of a list in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015439/why-does-map-return-a-map-object-instead-of-a-list-in-python-3/40015480#40015480) and we would need to convert it to `list` before printing it. Like so:

```
print(list(map(lambda x: ''.join(x), zip(*grid))), sep='\n')
```

Comment: Very interesting, thank you for sharing! At the time of writing this comment, I have not read about zip yet so implementation is based on loops and print alone but it is one to look out for, for sure!

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is to start by transposing the grid, then just loop over the elements of each row

```
 grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
         ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
         ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
         ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
         ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
         ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
         ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
         ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
         ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
  grid2=zip(*grid)
 # print(grid2)
  for row in grid2:
     for el in row:
         print(el, end='')
     print('\n')
```

Comment: You don't actually need to convert `grid2` into a `list`, since you can iterate over it.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your desired *output*, you'll observe that `final` matrix is `transpose` of your given list.

The `transpose` of a matrix could be found by using `numpy` *transpose* function.

You could use a *list comprehension* in combination with `join` method in order to achieve what you want.

```
import numpy as np
transpose = np.array(grid).transpose()
print('\n'.join([''.join(row) for row in transpose]))
```

Output

```
..00.00..
.0000000.
.0000000.
..00000..
...000...
....0....
```

Comment: I have heard of numpy but I am yet to use it. I will keep this mind, thank you very much.

Comment: @Mexen, you're welcome. Don't forget to vote answers in order to help other people.

Answer (score 1):

If you really must get the length of a list in a list, just use `len(grid[index])`:

```
for i in range(len(grid)):
    for j in range(len(grid[i])):
        print(mylist[i][j], end='')
    print()
```

However, it is easier to to iterate over the elements of the list than to get the indexes of the list. For example, instead of the above solution, use

```
for row in mylist:
    for element in row:
         print(element, end='')
    print()
```