# TypeError when split converting string to integer

Tags: python, string, split, integer, type-conversion

I get to read a line from a file that contain certain set of numbers per line. My problem is that the input is from a string line and then I need to process it as integer, making the conversion as [usually suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642154/how-to-convert-strings-into-integers-in-python). Although I check previous post on this problem, maybe because I am using structure and split can be the reason why the conversion is not working properly.

Here this error is popping up:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is a snapshot from the code I have done so far:

```
class Data:
    value1 = 0
    max = 10

class Process:
    value = None    
    def __init__(self):         
        self.input = Data()
    def __del__(self):          
        self.input

    def getValue(self,line):
        counter=0       
        for word in line.split():
            if counter == 0:
                self.input.value1=(int)word

        for number in self.input.max:
            if (number % self.input.value1 ==0):
                print(number)

    def readingFile(self):
        file = open(filename, "r")
        for line in file: 
            self.getValue(line)
```

Any suggestion what might be missing? I am running on Linux Python 3 using command line to compile.

Comment: can you put the traceback in the question?

Comment: The type conversion syntax is wrong. It should be `self.input.value1=int(word)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The invalid syntax comes from -

```
self.input.value1=(int)word
```

In python, the casting is not the same as in C/C++/Java , instead of using `(datetype)variable` you have to use `datatype(variable)` , though that is only for primitive datatypes. For other datatypes, you do not need casting, as python is a dynamically typed language.

You should use -

```
self.input.value1 = int(word)
```

### EDIT:

For the new error the OP is getting -

```
{{ for number in self.input.max: }} >> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.
```

You cannot iterate over an `int` object, just as the error indicates, to me it looks like both `self.input.value1` and `self.input.max` are single integers, so you may want to do -

```
if self.input.max % self.input.value1 == 0:
    print(self.input.max)
```

Comment: Now it gives the new error: {{ for number in self.input.max: }} >> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable. Thanks a ton!

Comment: The line that contains: {{ for number in self.input.max: }}

Comment: yes, like the line suggests you cannot iterate over integer, what do you want to accomplish with that?

Comment: Updated the answer for that as well , please check if that is really the requirement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80852/discussion-between-anand-s-kumar-and-daniela-martinez).

Comment: Thanks a lot. your suggestions solved the problem! I just needed to use "range" for the "for" loop to work with int