# Converts the character type in list to an integer

Tags: python

I have these data to convert it to integers.

```
['8737', '5330', '7463']
['690', '7227']
['4043', '1572']
['8334', '3227', '5642']
['3705', '3522']
```

I use **enumerate** to finish it:

```
for index, item in enumerate(list_a):
list_a[index] = int(item)
```

Is there other ways to finish it ?I try sting.atoi() to make it ,but it can only converts string to integer.

Comment: or list comprehension [int(x) for x in list]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert all strings in a list to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368789/convert-all-strings-in-a-list-to-int)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert strings into integers in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642154/how-to-convert-strings-into-integers-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#map) for this.

`list_a = list(map(int, list_a))`.

Comment: map returns a list ... you dont have to do `list()` again

Comment: @KaustavDatta Not in Python 3.