# How to convert String into integers in python sickit-learn

Tags: python, string, integer

I have a list as above:

```
probs= ['2','3','5','6']
```

and i want to convert those string to a numeric values like the following result:

```
resultat=[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I tried some solutions appearing on this link: 
[How to convert strings into integers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642154/how-to-convert-strings-into-integers-in-python)
such as this one:

```
new_list = list(list(int(a) for a in b) for b in probs if a.isdigit())
```

but it didn't work, someone can help me to adapt this function on my data structure, i will be really thankful.

Comment: `resultat = [int(item) for item in probs]`?

Comment: Just a problem with syntax. You are creating a list of lists. Instead, use: 

`new_list = list(int(a) for a in probs if a.isdigit())`

Comment: "but it didn't work, someone can help me to adapt this function on my data structure" - the structure is *simpler* than the one in the other question. Solving programming problems requires *understanding*, not just blind adaptation of existing code to the circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> probs= ['2','3','5','6']
>>> probs= map(int, probs)
>>> probs
[2, 3, 5, 6]
```

or (as commented):

```
>>> probs= ['2','3','5','6']
>>> probs = [int(e) for e in probs]
>>> probs
[2, 3, 5, 6]
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you @Billal for the answer. but i receive the following error:
ValueError:invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.00390625'

Comment: it must change int () on float() and it works really good. I appreciate it

Answer (score 4):

Use `int()` and list comprehension iterate the list and convert the string values to integers.

```
>>> probs= ['2','3','5','6']
>>> num_probs = [int(x) for x in probs if x.isdigit()]
>>> num_probs
[2, 3, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

if your list is as above, you don't need to check if the value is a number.
something like

```
probs = ["3","4","4"];
resultat = [];

for x in probs:
    resultat.append(int(x))

print resultat
```

would work

Comment: Thank you @Idco0 for the answer. but i receive the following error: 
 File " stdin", lin 2 
resultat.append(int(x))
IdentationError: expected an indented block