# Multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Tags: python, string

Hey guys im new here and im just starting out.
I tried to make a BMI calculator by simply getting input and doing calculations but it doesn't work for some reason.
This is the program:

```
print "how old are you?",
age = raw_input()
print "how tall are you?",
height = raw_input()
print "how much do you weigh?",
weight = raw_input()

print "So, you're %r years old, %r meters tall and %r Kilograms heavy.\n Ain't too bad but could be better to be honest!" %(age, height, weight)

print "Your BMI is %d" % (weight (height * height))
```

and this is the output:

```
how old are you? 1
how tall are you? 2
how much do you weigh? 4
So, you're '1' years old, '2' meters tall and '4' Kilograms heavy.
 Ain't too bad but could be better to be honest!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex10.py", line 11, in <module>
    print "Your BMI is %d" % (weight (height * height))
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

Thanks guys!!!

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't seperate the lines like it's in my code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your user input values are strings. You are trying to perform mathematical operations on them. You need to convert them to numbers first.

Here is a question that will set you on the path to converting the strings to integers:  [How to convert strings into integers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642154/how-to-convert-strings-into-integers-in-python)

Looking closer I believe your issue is that this line is incorrect:

```
print "Your BMI is %d" % (weight (height * height))
```

You're attempting to call a method `weight` passing in 2 strings multiplied. This won't work for several reasons. I believe you want:

```
print "Your BMI is %d" % (weight / (height * height))
```

Notice the division operator in there. I looked up BMI and found the equation to be weight over height squared.

Comment: I tried many of these but failed. If I understand correctly I should turn the string into int in the form of: height = int (height).

Comment: Have you tried: `print "Your BMI is %d" % (int(weight) (int(height) * int(height)))`?

Comment: Yes, it says : TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: I wrote your code locally and ran it. What are you attempting to do with `(weight (height * height))` ?  it looks like you're calling a method named weight? Were you possibly looking for `weight / (height * height)`?

Comment: Thanks jaydel! How stupid am I??? I also changed it to float instead of int so that it could take all numbers.