# Converting String element to int inside a tuple in Python

Tags: python, tuples

I have a tuple `a = (('1414', 'A'), ('1416', 'B'))` and I need to obtain the result as `result = ((1414, 'A'), (1416, 'B'))`.

I tried `tuple([map(int, x[0]) for x in a])` based on [How to convert strings into integers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642154/how-to-convert-strings-into-integers-in-python) and I get the result as `([1414], [1416])`. How would I maintain the result as a tuple with the changed value instead of making it as a list?

Comment: What would the code look like to turn `b = ('1414', 'A')` into `1414`? It would just be `int(b[0])`, right? No reason to use `map`? So, what happens if you then try applying *that logic* to the overall tuple of tuples? BTW, the described output does not match; in 2.x it would result in `([1, 4, 1, 4], [1, 4, 1, 6])`, and in 3.x the result is a pair of `map` objects. Considering the 2.x result carefully makes it clear where the fault is. But at any rate, this problem is caused by a typo and/or not reproducible.

Comment: Alternately: if the goal is to consider a tuple and convert only the values that are convertible *while preserving the other values*, and getting the tuple back - that is a different problem entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `map`:

```
azip = list(zip(*a))
out = list(zip(map(int, azip[0]), azip[1]))
```

Answer (score 4):

Using a generator expression:

```
a = (('1414', 'A'), ('1416', 'B'))

result = tuple((int(x[0]), x[1]) for x in a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda in `map()` which converts the first element in the tuple to an int.

```
a = (('1414', 'A'), ('1416', 'B'))
result = tuple(map(lambda x: (int(x[0]), x[1]), a))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
print(tuple([(int(i[0]),i[1]) for i in a]))
```

for detailed solution :

```
a = (('1414', 'A'), ('1416', 'B'))

new_list=[]

for i in a:
    new_list.append((int(i[0]),i[1]))

print(tuple(new_list))
```