# Turning list of strings into integers, but output is splitting digits instead of

Tags: python, string, list, types

So I have a list of numerical values that are of type string. Some of the elements of the list contain more than one numerical value, for instance:

`AC_temp= ['22', '45, 124, 12', '14', '12, 235']`

I'm trying to turn each of these elements into integers, while still conserving the sub-lists/tuples, so I want it to look like:

`AC_temp=[22, [45, 124, 12], 14, [12, 235]]`

When I run the following:

```
       for x in AC_temp:
           if "," in x: #multiple values
              val= x.split(",")
              print(val)
```

I get the output I expect:

```
 ['187', '22']
 ['754', '17']
 ['417', '7']
 ['819', '13']
 ['606', '1']
 ['123', '513']
```

But then when I try to turn them into ints via the following:

```
       for x in AC_temp:
           if "," in x:
              val= x.split(",")
              for t in val:
                  AC.append(map(int, t))
           else:
              AC.append(map(int, x)

       #print output#
       for i in AC:
           print(i)
```

It prints out the digits separately as such:

```
[1, 8, 7]
[2, 2]
[7, 5, 4]
[1, 7]
[4, 1, 7]
[7]
[8, 1, 9]
[1, 3]
[6, 0, 6]
[1]
[1, 2, 3]
[5, 1, 3]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert strings into integers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642154/how-to-convert-strings-into-integers-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `for`-loop, because `map` already iterates over the splitted elements:

```
   AC = []
   for x in AC_temp:
       if "," in x:
          val= x.split(",")
          AC.append(list(map(int, val))
       else:
          AC.append([int(x)])

   #print output#
   for i in AC:
       print(i)
```

or in a more compact form:

```
   AC = [list(map(int, x.split(","))) for x in AC_temp]

   #print output#
   for i in AC:
       print(i)
```

Comment: note that this doesn't preserve sublists -- to do that, change `.extend` to `.append`

Comment: @Daniel this returns `[[22], [45, 124, 12], [14], [12, 235]]`. Even the single elements are in lists.

Comment: That`s what the OP should want.

Comment: @Daniel I like your confidence.

Answer (score 0):

How about a `list-comprehension`?

```
AC_temp= ['22', '45, 124, 12', '14', '12, 235']

AC = [int(x) if ',' not in x else list(map(int, x.split(','))) for x in AC_temp]
print(AC)  # [22, [45, 124, 12], 14, [12, 235]]
```

---

*Note that if you are using **Python2**, you do not need to cast the `map` to `list`; it is already a `list`.*

Answer (score 0):

A nice readable way to do this is to gradually change the list using list comprehension:

```
AC_temp= ['22', '45, 124, 12', '14', '12, 235']

individual_arrays = [i.split(", ") for i in AC_temp]
# ...returns [['22'], ['45', '124', '12'], ['14'], ['12', '235']]

each_list_to_integers = [[int(i) for i in j] for j in individual_arrays]
# ...returns [[22], [45, 124, 12], [14], [12, 235]]
```

or alternatively, combined into one line:

```
numbers_only = [[int(i) for i in j] for j in [i.split(", ") for i in AC_temp]]
```

Then if you want you can break the single numbers out of their enclosing lists:

```
no_singles = [i[0] if len(i) == 1 else  i for i in each_list_to_integers]
```