# Iteration file with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, iteration

Do you have any suggestions for this script?

file.txt:

```
17
1
11
1
13
15
11
5
7
21
19
17
13
19
11
7
1
3
5
3
11
9
7
15
13
21
19
17
27
25
23
9001
9003
9023
9044
9055
9007
```

Code:

```
l2=[]
with open("file.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()
    l1 = list(data.split('\n'))
    for item in l1:
        if item>=9000:
            l2.append(item)
        else:
            item = item+9000
            l2.append(item)
print(l2)
```

Error:

```
    if item>=9000:
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert strings into integers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642154/how-to-convert-strings-into-integers-in-python)

Comment: Just run in Python 2, it will happily perform the comparison (and output the wrong answer!) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `item` is in a text file, it is a string, you should convert it to an `int` before comparing:

```
for item in l1:
    if item.isdigit():  # if it is a number
        item = int(item)  # convert it to int
        if item>=9000:
            l2.append(item)
        else:
            item = item+9000
        l2.append(item)
    else:  # not a number
        # do something
```

Comment: Returns this error
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: @Pydavide That may be caused by having something else in the file that is not a number, anyway, in my last edit I first see if the string is a representation of a number before converting it. It should work now.

Comment: @Pydavide Great. You should mark answers that you see best as 'correct'.