# How to convert string consisted of several numbers with a space into a list of integer values of that same string?

Tags: python, string, int

I have a string that consists of numbers with a space.

```
myString = "3 45 12"
```

I want to make a list of integer values derived from that string, ex:

```
myList = [3, 45, 12]
```

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642154/how-to-convert-strings-into-integers-in-python

Comment: @user2249207: that's only half the solution.

Comment: A simple 1 line solution: `myList = [int(i) for i in myString.split()]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
myString = "3 45 12"
numericdata = myString.split(' ')
numbers = []

for i in numericdata:
    numbers.append(int(i))

print(numbers)
```

Comment: it works, thank you!

Comment: @Sohib Welcome! and if it works than please accept the answer! Thankyou! :)

Comment: what if I had negative numbers in my string as well? I am receiving this error:     `numbers.append(int(i))

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'f'` I think it is related to negative integers in the string.

Comment: i think it doesn't matter if you have negative numbers to it will works fine unless you have a space in negative sign. are you using negative numbers like this : `- 2` or like this: `-2`

Comment: I am using as -2. Actually this a part of a code I am writing, your code is working separately, but when I insert inside another code, I have an error as I commented above.

Comment: Let me post it as a new question in a while

Comment: @Sohib Yeah it will be great if you do that

Comment: please refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510009/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10-f)