# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'f'

Tags: numpy, valueerror, opencv, python

I have been trying to iterate through text files to create some text files with the same name in other directory, but with other values. Here is the code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2, os
from glob import glob

path_in = 'C:/Users/user/labels'
path_out = 'C:/Users/user/labels_90'

for filename in os.listdir(path_in):
    if filename.endswith('txt'):
        filename_edited = []
        for line in filename:
            numericdata = line.split(' ')
            numbers = []
            for i in numericdata:
                numbers.append(int(i))
            c,x,y = numbers
            edited = [c, y, (19-x)]
            filename_edited.append(edited)
            filename_edited_array = np.array(filename_edited)

            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path_out,filename),filename_edited_array)

        continue
    else:
        continue
```

According to my plan, the code should access each text file, do some math with its each line, then create a text file storing the results of math.
When I run the code, it raises

```
numbers.append(int(i))

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'f'
```

I tried to look for answers but they do not suit to this situation I think

EDIT: I am providing text file example

```
0 16 6
-1 6 9
0 11 11
0 17 7
0 7 12
0 12 12
-1 19 4
```

Comment: the data in your `filename` are those all numbers ? or it also have text in it ? it seems like your are converting text to int

Comment: @Abdullah They are all numbers, both positive and negative integers. `filename` consists of numbers, but when I read each line of `filename` it is read as strings, that's why you provided 
            `numericdata = line.split(' ')
            numbers = []
            for i in numericdata:
                numbers.append(int(i))`

Comment: can you post the `filename` list/data here ? Or the numericdata list after performing that split operation ?

Comment: @AbdullahAhmedGhaznavi I edited the question

Comment: i have check that loop with all those numbers it doesn't gives me error. and by seeing your error i will recommend you that debug your filename loop and check that from where that `f` is comming in the list on which it gives you error while conversion in int

Comment: @Abdullah How do I debug my `filename`? What do you mean by `f` there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because with `for line in filename` you're not reading the file, you are iterating over the string containing the name of the file.

In order to read or write to a file you have to **open** it (and possibly to **close** it at the end of the operations).

The best and the most pythonic way to do it is to use the construct `with`, which closes it automatically at the end of the operations:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2, os
from glob import glob

path_in = 'C:/Users/user/labels'
path_out = 'C:/Users/user/labels_90'

for filename in os.listdir(path_in):
    if filename.endswith('txt'):
        filename_edited = []
        # open the file in read mode
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                numericdata = line.split(' ')
                numbers = []
                for i in numericdata:
                    numbers.append(int(i))
            # blah blah...
            # blah blah...
```

Comment: I see. Thank you. I somehow solved the problem, and what you mentioned was the thing I had found. That `f` gave a clue that I was actually reading the name of the file.