# How to convert a string element to a int variable from a list?

Tags: python, string, list, integer

I am quite new to python and have an issue where I am going to return an

Comment: `number = int(q[0])`? :)

Comment: if I understand correctly you want to have the number as an integer..try to cast it to an int.--> number = int(q[0])

Comment: I have tried that and it will jump to my return none value.

Comment: I missed this: rename the name of the argument from ***int*** to something else `def sizeofhome(uid):`, and also where it;s used: `if uid == line[2]:`

Comment: Cristifati this made the trick, thank you 3000 times <3. 7 hours of work and u solved it in 5min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in [[SO]: How to convert strings into integers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642154/how-to-convert-strings-into-integers-in-python), 
[[Python 3.Docs]: Built-in Functions - *class* **int**(*[x]*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=int#int) is used to convert an integer to a string:

> ```py
> >>> int('1586')
> 1586
> ```

But, by naming your function argument *int* you shadowed the **builtin *int*** (above), so the conversion is no longer possible. 
Renaming the argument to something else (I'd suggest ***uid***, to be in sync with *pwd*), the problem should go away:

- Function header:

  ```py
  def sizeofhome(uid):
  ```
- Function body:

  ```py
  if uid == line[2]:
  ```

As a general advice, when encountering such errors, use *print* (before the line that throws an exception), and also don't ignore the exception thrown.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you!

```
import subprocess
import re
import pwd

def sizeofhome(int):
   try:
       for line in pwd.getpwall():
           if int == line[2]:
               path = line[5]
               q = subprocess.check_output(["sudo", "du", "-sm", path]).decode()
               q = re.split("\s", q)
               number = int(q[0])
       return(number)
   except:  
       return None
```

Comment: If it returns None, your if condition is failing. check your if condition.

Comment: I have tried this and this will return none, not the number.

Comment: Other possible debug steps should be: 1. remove try except block and test 2. print line[2] to check what it holds to verify it matches int or not 3. print q before splitting to see if it holds desired value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  but christifati solved it!

Comment: Glad that it is solved :) Appreciated if you can say how