# How can I make a string and integer?

Tags: python

### What I am looking to do

So what I want to do, is get a string from an input, and convert it into an **int**. Here is a bit of the code so you have a picture of what I am aiming for.

```
age = input('How old are you: ')

for i in range(age, 18):
    print('I am', i, "years old")
```

I want to convert the string that I got from the input into an integer so I can use it in the i in range()... Is that possible?

Comment: `age = int(input('How old are you: '))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert strings into integers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642154/how-to-convert-strings-into-integers-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey in Python `input()` is by default store `string` type value. So you have to put

```py
age=int(input('How old are you: '))
```

Here `int()` will store `integer` type value.

OR

you can also do `int(age)`

Answer (score 0):

To do so you can use `int(age)`. You may want to implement a try/catch so that the program doesn't throw an exception when the input is invalid.

Comment: It's not a crash, it's  an exception that is thrown, with traceback telling your what went wrong, and then the "program" is terminated. A crash (e.g a segmentation fault) would end the script without any details.