# Python: How do I get rid of quotation marks on the last element of a nested list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, file-io, nested-lists

**Here is the entire question I am trying to solve:**

> Implement a function getCustomerList that takes as argument filename
> to read the file and return it as a nested list, where each element is
> a list of [, <Clerk’s Desk>, ]. The filename argument
> doesn’t contain the extension (i.e. “input”), your program must
> automatically add the “.txt” extension. If the file doesn’t exist, the
> getCustomerList function will print the message: “Error! 
> not found.”, and should return None.

**My Problem:**
I am having trouble in getting the last item (minutes) to return WITHOUT quotes.

**Here are my expected and actual results:**

> Name, Desk, Minutes

[image: Expected vs Actual results]

### Here is my code:

[image: My code]

```
def getCustomerList(filename):
    current_file = filename + ".txt"
    data = []

    # write code to check if file exist and return List/None
    try:
        open_file = open(current_file, "r")
   
        for aline in open_file:
            values = aline.split(",") # Break each line into a list
            lines = [(n.rstrip('\n')) for n in values]
            data.append(lines) # Add the row to the list
        return data[1:]
        print(data)
    
    except IOError:
        print("Error! " + current_file + " not found.")
```

Comment: @user202729 Thank you for the comment. I have updated my post.

Comment: Post the text for the expected output too (people might want to copy and paste it to run your code)

Comment: Although it looks like that you're looking for [How to convert strings into integers in Python? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642154/how-to-convert-strings-into-integers-in-python) .

Comment: @SuperStormer Thank you for the link, it helped me figure out my problem!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to transform into an integer? You can transform the last string of the list.

```
l = ['Annabel', 'A', '17']
l[-1] = int(l[-1])
print(l)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was able to fix my problem!

Answer (score 0):

#### I got it working:

**Actual**: [['Annabel', 'A', 17], ['Edgar', 'B', 19]]

**Expected**: [['Annabel', 'A', 17], ['Edgar', 'B', 19]]

#### Here is what I **added**:

```
    data.append(lines) # Add the row to the list

**for line in data [1:]:
    line[2] = int(line[2])**

return data[1:]
```