# I'm trying to make a password generator, but I get the error "Error: 'type' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Tags: python

```
import os, pyautogui, time, string, random, math
def random_numbers():
     random.randint(1, 100000000)
def random_char(y):
       return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for x in range(y))

def getinput(self, value):
    self.get = value


inp =input("Hello, Welcome to the password manager, Let's get you started.\nAt the moment, Only letters will work, but will still be sufficient for a secure password. Type OK to continue.\n")

if (str.lower(inp)) == "ok":
    userletters=input("How much letters would you like your password to be?\nEnter amount of letters: ")
    usernumbers=input("How much numbers would you like your password to be?\nEnter amount of numbers: ")
    usernumbers = int
    random_numbers = str
    userletters = str
    print(random_char(userletters)+(random_numbers()))
```

> Error:  'type' object cannot be interpreted as an integer   File
> "C:\Users\Noah\Desktop\PyNotDone\someting.py", line 5, in random_char
> return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for x in range(y))   File "C:\Users\Noah\Desktop\PyNotDone\someting.py", line
> 18, in 
> print(random_char(userletters)+(random_numbers()))

Why doesn't this work? After the usernumber variable line, it won't print anything.

Comment: Whatever you think `usernumbers = int` is doing, that's not what it does.  It makes `usernumbers` be an alias for the integer type.

Comment: Same thing with `random_numbers = str`: this doesn't create an empty string, or _any_ string - it makes `random_numbers` an alias of the `str` class

Comment: And your `random_numbers` doesn't return anything.  Shouldn't it return the number of digits the user asked for?  You're not even passing that as a parameter.

Comment: You pass `userletters` which is the string type to `random_char` which then passes it to `range` which expects ints. hence the error

Comment: Why is a function called `getinput` performing an assignment?! Is this code inside a class, or are you using `self` as a variable name?

Comment: Why is `userletters` not cast to `int` if you're planning on using it as a number as well? Wow there is so much wrong with this code. You really should go through some beginner tutorials on the basics of the Python language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def random_numbers(digits):
    return ''.join(str(random.randint(10) for i in range(digits))
...
usernumbers = int(usernumbers)
userletters = int(userletters)
print(random_char(userletters) + random_numbers(usernumbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is all the lines you have where you're trying to convert something to a type via:

```
something = int
```

That doesn't convert `something` from a `str` to an `int`, it just replaces `something`'s value with the literal type `int`, rather than a variable with the type of `int`.

To actually convert something from `str` to an `int`, see: [How to convert strings into integers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642154/how-to-convert-strings-into-integers-in-python)

Example:

```
usernumbers = int(input("How much numbers would you like your password to be?\nEnter amount of numbers: "))
```

Or:

```
usernumbers = input("How much numbers would you like your password to be?\nEnter amount of numbers: ")
usernumbers = int(usernumbers)
```

I think the real lesson here is that since programming is so exact and precise, that trying random things, like `something = int`, rather than searching for how to do the thing you want, is going to be problematic.