# Defining variable as long as array

Tags: python, wmi

I'm trying to write basic program that displays system properties such as total physical memory, processor information and operating system. But, I'm having trouble with learning ram total physical memory.

I found total physical memory but it gave me value as a string in bytes.

I wanted to convert it to mb so I have to convert it to an `int`.

I tried to split them as elements of an array. I separated them but, there is a problem. How can I
assign these values (elements of array) as `int` to a variable?

With a `for` loop?

My code is below:

```
import wmi

pc = wmi.WMI ()
for i in pc.Win32_ComputerSystem ():
  print(i.TotalPhysicalMemory)
  arr=list(i.TotalPhysicalMemory)
  length_of_array=len(arr)
for i in range(0, length_of_array):
    myvar=str(arr[i])
    print(myvar)
```

This code turns the physical memory string into an array and prints elements.

I want to turn `i.TotalPhysicalMemory` into an integer value and divide by `1000000`. How can I do it?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi It's not really relevant. `i.TotalPhysicalMemory` is a string. The question is just a roundabout way of asking how to divide a string by an integer.

Comment: @Axe319 ah, I see. I'm not familiar with wmi, and since OP said _" I found total physical memory but it gave me value in byte"_ I thought they meant it returns a `bytes` object.  Well, "string to int" that has lots of duplicates too, but somebody else will have to vote

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert strings into integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642154/how-to-convert-strings-into-integers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to turn TotalPhysicalMemory into an integer value and divide by 1000000. How can i do it?

to turn TotalPhysicalMemory into an integer, use `int(i.TotalPhysicalMemory)`. This doasn't overwrite the variable, so you'll have to save it in another one.

Comment: Sorry, i don't know how couldn't think that. Thanks!