# Comparison numbers in list

Tags: python, list

My question sounds retty stupid, but I really can't understand and solve this.

I try to find the biggest number in the list. There're only two numbers, my code:

```
list = ['7', '10']

a = list[0]
b = list[1]
if a > b :
    print('a')
else :
    print('b')
```

When I run it I get 'a', but why?

Comment: Because '7' (as a string) sorts after '1' (as a string).

Comment: Because you're _not_ comparing numbers, you're comparing _strings_ (that happen to represent numbers).

Comment: Why don't you use `list = [7, 10]` to create a list of numbers instead of strings

Comment: Your list holds strings, not numbers, so you need to change list type, or cast to number before comparing

Comment: Strings compare by first letter, a `1` is considered less than a `7` lexicographically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642154/how-to-convert-strings-into-integers

Comment: Thank you all, I'm really inattentive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problems with used data types. Both list values are strings, not integers. When comparing string values you are trying to compare characters starting from left.

So when comparing '7' and '10' computer first compares first chars of each string by its unicode values, so  '7' and '1'. And because 1 (unicode 49) is less than 7 (unicode 55), you receive this result.

So you need to either change the list items type to integer:

```
list = [7, 10]
```

or cast values to integer before comparing:

```
a = int(list[0])
b = int(list[1])
```

You could convert your list to int, then use build in max function. This approach is better when the size of the list is dynamic

```
int_list = [int(x) for x in list]
print(max(int_list))
```